# Реализация асинхронного многопоточного приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

При выполнении асинхронного многопоточного приложения на  Windows Forms возникла следующая задача, решение которой я до сих пор найти не могу, поэтому обращаюсь к вам.

Суть задачи:

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы задачи в `listBox` отображались списком, и каждая задача при этом выполнялась, пока не закончится.

Пытался выполнить так: по `id` задачи в списке `ListBox` находится соответствующий этому `id` элемента, и редактируется соответствующая запись (показывается что процесс выполняется).

Вопросы:

Как можно получить `id` каждой задачи? Может код асинхронный не правильно написал? Прошу ваших замечаний и предложений.

В настоящий момент программа работает, даже вроде как и выполняются задачи правильно, только отобразить их так, чтобы они все сразу отображались и правильно редактировались (обновлялись) не получается.

Код С#

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ...........
         // код           
             ........... 

                await Task.Factory.StartNew(translator.TranslatorMethod);
 // ......код
     listBox1.Items.Add(translator.Text + " = " + binary + ", " + hexadecimal);

            }

        }




 private void translator_ProcessChange(int progress)
       {
       Action action = () =>
       {
          listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.Add(translator.Text + " , будет посчитано через " + progress.ToString() + " секунд");

        };

          Invoke(action);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто.

Для начала, запуском задач и свойствами задачи должна заниматься модель (или VM) в зависимости от архитектуры вашего приложения. Под каждую из задач должен быть выделен экземпляр класса, описывающего эту задачу. Этот класс должен точно знать состояние задачи и рассылать нотификацию (`INotifyPropertyChanged`?) при изменении состояния.

У вас должен быть список (`ObservableCollection`?) задач (то есть, объектов, описывающих задачу). Модельная часть программы запускает задачи и обеспечивает обновление данных. UI (или Controller, в зависимости от архитектуры) должен следить за обновлениями списка и объектов в нём, и обновлять UI.

Никакой специальной обработки для асинхронных задач не нужно: вы просто показываете список изменяющихся со временем объектов. То, что эти объекты представляют собой выполняющуюся в другом потоке задачу — деталь имплементации, не интересная на уровне UI.

---

```
enum TranslationState { NotStarted, Running, Successful, Failed };

class TranslationRun : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    TranslationState state = TranslationState.NotStarted;
    public TranslationState State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { if (value != state) { value = state; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    string result = null;
    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { if (value != result) { value = result; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        StartAsync().Ignore();
    }

    Task StartAsync()
    {
        State = TranslationState.Running;
        try
        {
            Result = await Task.Run(DoTranslation);
            State = TranslationState.Successful;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            State = TranslationState.Failed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ! А можно ссылку где про эту тему по подробней прочитать можно или есть похожий реализованный код?

Comment: @Vladimir: Даже не знаю. Попробуйте почитать про паттерн MVC, должно быть то, что надо. Но там много, сразу говорю.

Comment: @Vladimir: Примерный код набросать не смогу, я не спец в WinForms. На WPF это делается немного проще.

Comment: Без разницы на чём главное что бы идею понять можно было. Только по моему вы меня не так немного поняли я имел в виду десктопное WindowsForms приложение, а не web.

Comment: @Vladimir: WPF — это тоже десктопный фреймворк, более продвинутый, чем WinForms.

Comment: По моему я понял, про что вы писали. Т.е. в проекте должен быть класс который за это отвечает(модель). И каждый раз при кликании по мыши должен создаваться экземпляр этого класса. Который представляет эту задачу.

Comment: @Vladimir: Добавил в ответ пример работы модельного класса. Как UI будет подхватывать изменения — зависит от конкретного UI-фреймворка.

Comment: @Vladimir: Именно так. В этом и состоит суть MVC.